# Multiple hover_name for 3D plot in Python Plotly

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I would like to add more hover text using multiple columns for my 3D plot model.

For example:
`df`:

```
    sepal_length    sepal_width petal_length    petal_width species species_id
0   5.1             3.5         1.4             0.2         setosa  1
1   4.9             3.0         1.4             0.2         setosa  1
2   4.7             3.2         1.3             0.2         setosa  1
3   4.6             3.1         1.5             0.2         setosa  1
4   5.0             3.6         1.4             0.2         setosa  1
5   5.4             3.9         1.7             0.4         setosa  1
```

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                    color='petal_length', symbol='species', hover_name="species")
fig.show()
```

produced plot [image]

In the plot, the `hover_name="species"` shows only `species` in the `hover_name`. How can I include `species_id` in `hover_name` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add additional information in `hover_data` argument below:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                    color='petal_length', symbol='species', hover_name="species", hover_data=["species", "species_id"])
fig.show()
```

Docs could be found here [Customizing Hover text with Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/)